# How to restrain the image size in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to restrain the varies image widht and height inside a `div`.

The images have different size and I want to reduce the image size while maintaining it's ratio if it's oversize.

```
 $('#Div').css({display:'block',
                     position: 'absolute',
                     top: offset.top,
                     left:offset.left
                     }).append("<img src='" + largePic+ "'/>");
```

The `largePic` is the large image path and I can't tell how big the image is until it loads.

Any idea how to do this? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If you constrain just one property (either width or height) the other one adjusts. do you know the proportions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can constrain the image by way of the div, or the image.  Here's a jsfiddle of constraining the image by setting a width on the div, and having the image fill the div as best possible: http://jsfiddle.net/LELns/

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS [`max-width`](http://quirksmode.org/css/width.html) property on the div.

Something like this should work:

```
$('#Div').css({display:'block',
                 position: 'absolute',
                 top: offset.top,
                 left:offset.left,
                 max-width: '200px'
                 }).append("<img src='" + largePic+ "'/>");
```

Comment: nope, I have tried Max-width and Max-height, but the images are still bigger than my div.. +1 though

Comment: @FlyingCat have you tried setting the `max-width` property to the image itself?

Comment: @FlyingCat Try with the image too, just in case

Answer (score 1):

Constrain it with a max-height, or a max-width.